# Candle chart view in MPChart library zoom issue on android application

Tags: mpandroidchart, candlestick-chart

I have a requirement to plot the candle chart with 100 years worth of data, for the years 1920 to 2020. When I plot the graph using mp chart, it shows all 100 years of data on graph.

My requirement is to show the last 20 years of data (form 2001 to 2020) when rhw app launched. In addition, users should be able to scroll the graph from right to left to see remaining years of data on the graph.

I've used this code:

```
mChart.setVisibleXRange((mChart.getXChartMax()-mChart.getXChartMin())/3);
```

However, this divides the graph view in 3 parts and shows data from 1920 to 1956.

Please help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the range **after** you setData(), invalidate() or notifyDataChangeSet()

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20);
```

If you want to scroll the X to right you can use this:

```
mChart.moveViewToX(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```